# Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed array does not specify an existing static method' error in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana-3

I'm new to Kohana and trying to configure a existing project on my local machine. I changed the bootstrap.php and related ini file. When I tried to view the landing page, I got error as follows

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed
>   array does not specify an existing static method' in
>   E:\xxxxx\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\application\bootstrap.php:27
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xxxxx\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\application\bootstrap.php(27):
>   spl_autoload_register() #1
>   E:\xxxxx\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\index.php(102):
>   require('E:\xxxxx...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xxxxx\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\application\bootstrap.php
>   on line 27

Why I'm getting this error, I'm not able to trace it.

Comment: It would help if you copied line 27 and the surrounding area.

Answer (score 3):

The line (bootstrap.php:27) should look something like

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load'));
```

***You should not need to change this line.***

The error is simply complaining that the array does not specify the name of an available static method, in this case that would be `Kohana::auto_load()` (actually defined as `Kohana_Core::auto_load()`, the `Kohana` class extends `Kohana_Core`). In your case, however you changed that line, it does not point to a static method.

Comment: I have not changed the line. Still, I copied the line from bootstrap.php from recent copy, but still the error is there :(

Comment: Have you changed `index.php` at all? This is the file which `require()`s the file defining that method.